# Picking a Random Variable out of an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what my problem is here.  I'm working on this in jsfiddle.  I have a div in html that's just a box and I want to append a string to it from a variable using jquery.

```
var spongebob='pineapple';
var patrick='rock';
var sandy = 'air dome';
var mrKrabs = 'anchor';
var house = [spongebob, patrick, sandy, mrKrabs];
var pickHouse= house[Math.floor(Math.random * house.length)];
$('div').append(pickHouse);
```

I have a feeling my problem is in my second to last line but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var spongebob='pineapple';
var patrick='rock';
var sandy = 'air dome';
var mrKrabs = 'anchor';
var house = [spongebob, patrick, sandy, mrKrabs];
var pickHouse= house[Math.floor(Math.random() * house.length)];
$('div').append(pickHouse);
```

You forgot the parenthesis in `Math.random()` (hence getting `NaN` for the index)